# passing an object in javascript function on onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jstl

I am trying to pass an object to a javascript function which should trigger when a link is clicked. But unfortunately I am not able to get it working.

Here is the code on my jsp file for the same:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function tryToDoItTwice(obj) {
            var check = obj;
            if(check == null) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert("You're not allowed to do this twice!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
</script>

<a href="<c:url value="/somepath" />" onclick="javascript: tryToDoItTwice(${foo});">Try to do it twice</a>
```

Here `foo` refers to an object of type `Foo`.

Could someone help me understand what am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**: `Foo` is a java object. and `${foo}` is a reference variable referring to `Foo` java object.

Thanks.

Comment: I would say learn Javascript before JQuery. What is ${foo} never seen such syntax.

Comment: Also, no need to put `javascript` inside the onclick attribute. And, give us the error message.

Comment: I need a clarification.. the function is never being called right?

Comment: @Itay: Its a reference to an object of type Foo. Its expression language used on jsp pages. I am passing this object from a controller to this jsp page.

Comment: Is this object tranlated to Javascript behind the scenes?

Comment: Also, is foo a session object?

Comment: @Lucky: How do I check if the function is being called? In firebug I see the value of `${foo}` happily shown in the argument of `tryToDoItTwice(${foo})`.

Comment: @Lucky: No, `foo` is not a session object.

Comment: Can you check Firebug console and confirm that it is not throwing any error?

Comment: @Itay: I am not sure it being translated into JSON as I see it as a reference of java object being passed on the javascript method using jasp expression language? What am I missing here? Am I not allowed to do that? Can't I pass an object of any type to a javascript method?

Comment: @Lucky: I clicked on the console button on firebug with show javascript errors option on and it doesn't show anything on the console. It doesn't show any errors. What am I missing?

Comment: can you paste the value of ${foo} u see in firebug? i.e., please paste how this line is shown in firebug `<a href="<c:url value="/somepath" />" onclick="javascript: tryToDoItTwice(${foo});">Try to do it twice</a>`

Comment: @Lucky: Here comes an error saying $ is not defined on `$(document).ready(function() {`. What does it mean? :(

Comment: @Lucky: `<a onclick="javascript: tryToDoItTwice(com.myproject.domain.Foo@8a88a9);" href="/myproject/somepath">Try to do it twice</a>` this is what I see on firebug for the link.

Comment: `$ is not defined ` is not defined when you don't include jquery.js.

Comment: @Lucky: The jsp include at the top has all the `jqeury-1.5.js` included. I wonder how come its not working. But after including the `jquery-1.5.js` locally the error has gone. Am I not allowed to pass a java object reference in a javascript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a JAVA object directly to javascript. Either you need to return as JSON ( look up GSON or Jackson for converting object to JSON ) or pass variables( not object ) to the function.

Comment: Oops, I guess I should have explicitly mentioned that in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your `check` variable is locally scoped to that function so it will be redeclared each time the function is called (not storing your value the next time it's clicked.

You need to expand the scope of your variable.

```
 var check = null;
  $(document).ready(function() {
        function tryToDoItTwice(obj) {
            check = obj;
            if(check == null) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert("You're not allowed to do this twice!");
                return false;
            }
        }
});
```

Also, if `foo` exists elsewhere, you probably just want to pass it in like this:

`<a href="<c:url value="/somepath" />" onclick="javascript: tryToDoItTwice(foo);">Try to do it twice</a>`

Comment: Don't go by the name of the function. I think he is getting the number of clicks from Server-side rather than Client side..